# Different kinds of exception handling in nestjs (graphql)

Tags: rest, exception, graphql, microservices, nestjs

I am using GraphQLFederationModule in my nestjs project and now working on the exceptions handling part. I use **formatError** to catch all the exceptions thrown in resolvers.

Basically I have 4 kinds of source of exception:

1. Error in resolver/service logic that not related to other services.
2. Error from database, which is mongoDb (using nestjs/mongoose).
3. Error when calling api from other graphql servers using graphql-request.
4. Error when calling api from other restful api servers using axios.

For each kind of exceptions I need to handle it differently. So the question is, how can I determine which kind of exception it is from the error passed into formatError ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a "good" way to solve this so I just determine them by the content:
https://github.com/VictorCheng114668/nestjs-helper/blob/main/graphqlModule-formatError-helper/exceptionsHandler.ts

Comment: I was unable to find your repository. But your answer also makes sense for my case.